# Return Value Based on Conditional Lookup from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Objective: to lookup value from one data frame (conditionally) and place the results in a different dataframe with a new column name

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Code':[80.06, 82.,80.,82.06,82.01,83.,80.02,85.,82.13],'Price':[11,21,25,36,43,55,66,77,88]})
df1= pd.DataFrame({'Code':[82.06,82.05,82.13,80.02,80.02,80.05,80.02,80.02,80.02,83.12,82.01]})
df1['Price'] = np.where((df.Code==df1['Code']), df['Price'], '')
print(df1)
```

I want to find for df1 Codes prices from df but it writes error
"ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

I want output to be:

```
  Code Price
0   82.06    36
1   82.05    N/A
2   82.13    88
3   80.02    66
4   80.02    66
5   80.05    N/A
6   80.02    66
7   80.02    66
8   80.02    66
9   83.12    N/A
10  82.01    43
```

Comment: Sorry for mess, i wrote what kind of output i want, thanks @yatu

Comment: ```df1.merge(df,on='Code',how='left')```

Comment: doesn't work. this code only show codes, not price @sammywemmy

Comment: I followed @sammywemmy's comment and did it. I got the code column and price column correct.

Comment: I checked it again and it works. thanks  @sammywemmy and @ r-beginners